# Understanding the mantissa part of a 32 bit float for the decimal 0.2

Tags: binary, floating-point

Why is 0.2d equal to a binary representation of: 0 0111110010011001100110011001101

So 0.2d can translate into 0.0011b repeating. You move the radix over and get 1.1 x 2^-3

sign bit = 0

exponent = 0111 1100

mantissa = 10011001100110011001101 why?

Wouldn't the mantissa just be 10000000000000000000000?

Comment: No, because a mantissa of 10000… would correspond to a power of two, which 2/10 isn't.

Comment: @PascalCuoq,: actually a manitssa of all 0s corresponds to a power of 2 (because of the hidden 1 bit).  A mantissa of 10000... corresponds to 1.5 times a power of 2 (which would be 0.1875 in this case -- 3/16)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0.2 decimal is 0.001100110011... in binary.  When you shift that have a `1` before the decimal point (required, as that `1` is not actually stored in the fp value -- its the "hidden" one), you have 2<sup>-3</sup> · 1.1001100110011...  Now if you actually want to store exactly 23 bits of mantissa (as with fp32), the break:

```
10011001100110011001100_110011001..
```

comes at a point just before a 1 bit, so you round that up, giving

```
10011001100110011001101
```

as the stored mantissa